# Angular 7 Prevent Another function to use "If" Condition

Tags: javascript, angular

```
  How to Use IF condition inside function for only one call and not to use for other call
```

I have a function below it is invoked twice but the first "IF" Condition inside function should 
       be invoked only when i click add bank button and not for edit bank

```
private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName) {

            if(countryName === 'China'){
              this.payment.bankAccountName = null;
              this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
             }


       else if (countryName === 'China') {
          this.selectedCountryValidator = '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$';
          this.accountBeneficiaryName = 'Simplified Chinese characters - 简化字 ';
          this.branchNameLocal = 'Simplified Chinese characters - 简化字 ';
          this.bankNameLocal = 'Simplified Chinese characters - 简化字 ';
        } else {
          this.selectedCountryValidator = '';
          this.accountBeneficiaryName = 'Please provide account (Beneficiary) name';
          this.branchNameLocal = 'Please provide branch name';
          this.bankNameLocal = 'Please provide institution name';
        }
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }



When i add a bank and when i edit a bank it is invoked but my problem is i want the function to be invoked twice but i want the if condition*( if(countryName === 'China'){
          this.payment.bankAccountName = null;
          this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
         } )*
inside the function to be invoked only on Add Bank 

Add Bank function is like this 

      <button (click)="addBank(payment, 'BANK_ADD')">
                  Add Bank
                </button>

Edit Bank is like this

     <img (click)="editSearchPaymentTabInfo('SUPPLIER_BANK_UPDATE', banks, 'BANK_UPDATE')"/>
```

i wrote like this but no luck

```
private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName,textAccessHeader) {
    if(textAccessHeader ==="BANK_ADD"){
    if(countryName === 'China'){
      this.payment.bankAccountName = this.payment.bankAccountName ;
      this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass 'BANK_ADD' or edit to your `checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries` function

```
checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName, bankAction){
  if(backAction === 'BANK_ADD){
  //do your bank add thing
}
```

Comment: Hi it shows error   this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name,bankAction); arguments expectes two but provided only one

Comment: private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName,textAccessHeader) {
    if(textAccessHeader ==="BANK_ADD"){
    if(countryName === 'China'){
      this.payment.bankAccountName = this.payment.bankAccountName ;
      this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(nameOfCountry, action){
  if(action === 'BANK_ADD'){}
  else if(action==='BANK_UPDATE'){}
}
```

While calling call like this:

```
this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries('India', 'BANK_ADD')
```

Comment: Bribes on SO probably won't go well

Answer (score 0):

you can add a flag in your function calling like below this

```
<button (click)="addBank(payment, true)">
                  Add Bank
                </button>
```

and in your function add one if for check this flag value

```
if(flag) {
if(countryName === 'China'){
              this.payment.bankAccountName = null;
              this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
             }
}
```

so in case of Edit Bank, you can set flag false and in Add Bank, you can set flag true